# PIG - how to use shell command for pattern file/folder names

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

Is there a way to use such syntax in pig script?

**Command:**

```
/* some pig latin code here */

mv /user/test/folder_pattern* /path/to/move

/* some pig latin code here */
```

**Error:**

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File or directory /user/test/folder_pattern* does not exist.
```

When I point the full path to folder withou '*' it works.
How can I mv, cp, rm files by pattern like with hdfs fs or in bash?

Comment: What does your folder_pattern look like and why do you have a * after the pattern?If you want everthing under /user/test/ moved then mv  /user/test/* /path/to/move/ should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the 'sh' to run shell commands from both the grunt shell and pig scripts.

Syntax:- sh subcommand subcommand_parameters

For the code which you have provided, it would look something like this -

```
/* some pig latin code here */

sh mv /user/test/folder_pattern* /path/to/move

/* some pig latin code here */
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Can you paste your code here,
This is my pig script 
sh mv /home/cloudera/ankit/wor* /home/cloudera        which runs fine. the name of the file is work.txt.